# .NET Windows Service - Pulling Updates with Service Restart

Tags: .net, windows, service

None of the following has been attempted - I have no idea if it's possible, or, for that matter, where to start.  I'm presenting a hypothetical scenario for a project I'd like to attempt.

Situation:  I provide a windows service to a remote client (customer), where they install the service on their server.

Issue:  Somewhere down the road there's a bug in the service.  I need to provide a fix **without providing a brand new version of the service** to the end user (where they uninstall the old, buggy version and install a new one).

Questions:  Is it possible to have the remote user restart the service and, upon starting, have the service detect that an updated version of an assembly, or a new assembly is available that fixes the bug(s).  In other words, can a service detect updates somewhat like a click once application?  I have a feeling that this is not possible.  If it's not, do you have any other suggestions?

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you're looking for functionality similar to ClickOnce you could write your own.  All of the ClickOnce functionality exists in the System.Deployment namespace.

Here's a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140611095049/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/wriju/archive/2006/06/10/625276.aspx) to help you get started and a [web cast](https://msevents.microsoft.com/cui/webcasteventdetails.aspx?eventid=1032271419&eventcategory=3&culture=en-us&countrycode=us) that should be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Tyler,

Can you put you logic into a webservice hosted by yourself, if not you may want to look at using MEF Directory Catalog, to view a folder without having to compile it.

http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20catalogs

Hope this help

Iain